# IntelliJ can't find OJDBC driver in debug mode

Tags: intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception, grails-3.0, ojdbc

I am trying to debug my grails 3.09 application using IntelliJ IDEA 15.
It errors out with class Not Found Exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

I feel IntelliJ can't find the ojdbc driver.

Any suggestions to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is the dependency in your build.gradle?

Did you do "Refresh all Gradle projects"?
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html